# CSS: dynamic width of elements

Tags: html, css

If you check the site im currently working on:
http://4rate.org/

I want the squares to be evenly aligned to the users screen width, so everything will look "centered",
with no extra space on either side. I could hardcode the widths to match perfectly with my own screen, but then everyone which dont have my screen, will not have it look perfect.

I discovered that for example if i browse this site on my sony z3 compact, there will be 3 squares per line, and a pretty big "extra space" on the right side of the screen.

Same thing would apply for different screen sizes with different users.

How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below**

Update the class `.ratingdiv` by updating `float:left` with `display:inline-block` and adding `vertical-align:top` to get this fixed..

**CSS:**

```
.ratingdiv {
    background-color: #f0e0d6;
    border: 1px solid #d9bfb7;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 280px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 255px;
}
```

Comment: wow man. magic. what is the stuff behind this, that makes it "auto width" ?

Comment: not a rocket science behind that.. the attr 'float:left' always force the element to stay on extreme left of the wall

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using a Javascript framework to accomplish this, or by using CSS media queries. Even something like Bootstrap can accomplish this quite easily.